# Unexpected character ( ` ) error when using UglifyJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, uglifyjs

While running uglifyjs, I get the above error. The code looks like this:

```
$('.lazyload').each(function(i,j){
    var h = $(j).attr( 'height' );
    var w = $(j).attr( 'width' );
    var at = `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ${w} ${h}"%3E%3C/svg%3E`;
    $(j).attr('src', at);
});
```

I read that I would need to transpile it down to ES5, but I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to to that.

Comment: Please add the error output to make it easier for others to help

Comment: I used [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es), which worked great for my simple application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uglify-js [only supports ECMAScript 5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js). This explains why you get an error on the line that has the template literal, which is a syntax introduced with ECMAScript 2015:

```
 var at = `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ${w} ${h}"%3E%3C/svg%3E`;
 //       ^ error
```

You can do the same assignment without template literal, using single quoted literals and concatenation:

```
var at = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ' 
       + w + ' ' + h + '"%3E%3C/svg%3E';
```

Alternatively you could follow the advice on [uglify-js home page (github)](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#readme)

> To minify ECMAScript 2015 or above, transpile using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).